# R cannot be resolved to a variable on CastCompanionLibrary in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cast, r.java-file

I want to use CastComponaionLibrary but I'm using Eclipse and not Android Studio. So I created a new project and copied all CastCompanionLibrary sources into it. I also added references to:

- android-support-v4
- android-support-v7-appcompat
- android-support-v7-mediarouter
- google-play-services_lib

In this new project I get these compilation errors:

R cannot be resolved to a variable  MiniController.java /CastCompanionLibrary-android-master/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/widgets line 87 Java Problem

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files VideoCastControllerActivity.java
any ideas?

Comment: A missing `R` class indicates a problem with one of your resources, or with your manifest. Look for the red X's in Eclipse's Package Explorer, or examine your Errors view, to try to determine where the problem lies.

Comment: This code is copy from https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android , so I guess it should be wrong in the library or environment settings?

Comment: You may try to (a) Clear all projects, (2) Close and open eclipse. Sometimes eclipse gets very moody and you need to try a few tricks to get it back to cooperating with you. That library has all the needed resources, so don't try to look for a solution there. In terms of referencing the support libraries, first you don't need v4 since it is included in v7. Then make sure you have correctly set them up: mediarouter has dependency on appcompat and both need to be imported as projects not copying the jars. We have a video for that: https://plus.google.com/117916055521642810655/posts/NxcYH6yPeUj

Answer (score 0):

You would need to import android-support-v7-gridlayout as an existing project as well and add it to: Preferences->Android->Add.

Also the ...-mediarouter must be linked with ...-appcompat in order to work properly.

Once you cleaned all the .xml files (I mean no errors at all) you can do a clean and this should do the trick.

And obviously you don't need v4 as long you make use of v7 (everything is included in the newer version).

Reference: http://blog.burnayev.com/2009/11/android-developer-tip-regenerating.html

Answer (score 0):

Because:

`R.java is the dynamically generated class, created during build process to dynamically identify all assets (from strings to android widgets to layouts), for usage in java classes in Android app. Note this R.java is Android specific (though you may be able to duplicate it for other platforms, its very convenient) so it doesnt have much to do with Java language constructs. Take a look here, for more details.`

=> R class is reference package in Manifest, so when you create new project, you should replace package in `CastCompanionLibrary` by your new package in Manifest. But remember copy Resource in `res` directory because R class will use it

Hope it's helpful